# How to query (Top level where) eagerly loaded belongsToMany Associations in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Let's say I have the following models(one book has multiple authors, and an author can be participate in multiple books) :

```
const Book = sequelize.define('book', {...});
const Author = sequelize.define('author', {...});
Book.belongsToMany(Author, { through: BookAuthor });
```

I'm trying to query for books with title like 'nodejs' and the author name is 'John Doe', limit the first 10, how do I accomplish such a query?

Using the approach described here http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#eager-loading doesn't seem to work with belongsToMany associations.

adding a Where clause in the include section, will filter the result from main query, therefore it will return the first ten, in this case, then filter that.

EDIT:

the query I'm trying is:

```
Book.findAndCountAll({ include: [{ model: Author, where: { name: 'shakespeare' } } ], limit: 10, offset: 0 })
                     .then((results) => { console.log(results.rows.length); // -> 0, wrong 
                     console.log(results.count) // -> 2, correct 
});
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a query that you've tried?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm trying something like: 
 ```Book.findAndCountAll({ include: [{ model: Author, where: { name: 'shakespeare' } } ], limit: 10, offset: 0 })
.then((results) => {
    console.log(results.rows.length); // -> 0, wrong
console.log(results.count) // -> 2, correct 
});``` it looks like there are results, but not in the first page, if no limit applied, then the result is what's expected.

Comment: Have you tried using `findAll` instead of `findAndCountAll`?

Comment: Yes, I have, `findAll` gets me the wrong result, just like `results.rows` that `findAndCountAll` returns.

Comment: try this thread: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3036#issue-56065947